# Use a pipe in a thread function

Tags: c

I have to do a function that contains two threads. One has to read one pipe and the other has to write in another pipe. But I dont know how to pass the pipe yo the thread function, because there is another structure that has to go in the arguments part of the pthread_create.
I'll put some code if it's a little clearer this way.

```
void *readFather(Job *job){
    write (desc1Pipe[0],job->in, job->size_in);
}

void *writeFather(Job *job){
if ((job->size=read (desc2Pipe[1], job->out,  job->max_out) > job->max_out) 
    kill(job->pidhijo,SIGKILL);                        
}
```

Those are the functions I give to pthread_create.

This is the calling of the threads.

```
pthread_t pid1; 
pthread_t pid2;
...
pthread_create(&pid1, NULL, readFather, &job);      
pthread_create(&pid2, NULL, writeFather, &job);
```

Please help me, I've done all I can think of, I'm really new to all C related stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have multiple pieces of data you can wrap them in a struct.

```
struct readData
{
    Job *job;
    int  fd;
};

...

struct readData readData;

readData.job = job;
readData.fd  = pipeFd;

pthread_create(&pid1, NULL, readFather, &readData);
```

Comment: But if I put the pipe descriptor in the structure, it still writes and reads the data in the pipe?

Comment: File descriptors are just ints, so yes, you can use them in another thread if you have the same int(s).